Node.js Unexpected token '.'
I'm new in linux, js and node.js development so sorry if this question is stupid...but.
I have my first app on my local test server. When I go to the folder with the code and type npm start, everything works correctly.
BUT
I wanted to run it on the background and use systemctl to work with the app. But When I use sudo systemctl start "my app" I'm getting
Please help me :/
Unexpected token '.'
Stopping My Eclipse Application... eclipse.service: Deactivated successfully. Stopped My Eclipse Application. Started My Eclipse Application. eclipse@1.0.0 start nodemon server.js [nodemon] 3.1.0 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `r\>
\[nodemon\] watching path(s): *.*
\[nodemon\] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,\>
\[nodemon\] starting `node server.js`
/var/www/projects/eclipse/node_modules/mon\>
session: options?.session,
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/load\>
at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/c\>
at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (inte\>
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/l\>
at Function.Module.\_load (internal/mod\>
at Module.require (internal/modules/cj\>
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpe\>
at Object.\<anonymous\> (/var/www/projec\>
at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/c\>
at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (inte\>
\[nodemon\] app crashed - waiting for file c\>\


.service
[Unit]
Description=My Eclipse Application

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm start
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/projects/eclipse
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Node.js v20.12.2.
nodemon -v3.1.0
nvm -v0.39.7
I've tried to update nvm, nodemon, node. Run it only like nvm start from the app folder.

I think just wrong copy paste :) what now?

If you have a (very out of date?) system Node, uninstall it to avoid confusion – this service probably isn’t using your nvm-installed Node. Then use nvm which node and specify the full path.

@Ry- so i tried to run sudo apt-get remove nodejs and then nvm which node
[Unit]
Description=My Eclipse Application
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/polakon/.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.2/bin/node/npm start
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/projects/eclipse
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
but this didn't help
Again.. I'm very new in this

Wrong path to the node.
pasting path from nvm which node helped
